# Retrieve a C global variable from a program other than where the variable is defined

Tags: c++, c, function, return, global-variables

Suppose I have a C program foo.c which uses a global variable 'i'

```
int i;

foo(x){
  i = x*x;
}
```

Wihtout modifying the program foo.c, is there a mechanism in C/C++ for us  retrieve the value of i for a given ‘x’, for example,  by devising a  C/C++ program that wraps foo.c like:

```
int foo2(x){
  foo(x);
  return the value of i stored in memory when computing foo(x);
}
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Do you mean without modifying `i`?

Comment: @imreal. Thanks.  I said "without modifying the program foo.c".

Comment: I meant, without modifying the value of `i`?

Comment: Hey, you, the downvoter,  a learner wants to learn.

Comment: Surely if it's a global you don't need to _retrieve_ it per-se, you can just reference it since it has global scope?

Comment: @Component10 I did not know that we can retrieve that variable from another file. Thanks.

Comment: @zell Apologies, I did not realise that this was from another file. In that case Borgleaders suggestion is probably what you want in your other file.

Comment: @Component10 Because we require foo.c be unchanged, the only way to retrieve the value of i is from another file. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is already accessible from any other compilation unit, provided you declare it beforehand.

You can just declare it and then access it:

```
extern int i;
int foo2(/*type*/ x){
  foo(x);
  // i is available here
}
```

Comment: You might want to add 'return i' at the end

Answer (score 2):

> I believe, in your question, "program" reffers to "function"

1. If the wrapper function is present in the same compilation unit (usually, source file), you can use `i` directly inside the wrapper function as mentioned below. `i` is a global.
2. To make use of `i` from some other translation unit (ex. some other function present in some other source file), you can `extern` the declaration of the same variable and make use of that.

   ```
   extern int i;   //extern declaration of `i` in some other file, 
                   //where the wrapper function is present
   ```

After that,  you can always *copy* the value of `i` before operation and `return` that value. Once you keep a *copy* of the previous value, the changed value of `i` won't make impact there. Something like

```
int foo2(x){

  int temp = i;
  foo(x);
  return temp;  //will return the value of i before calling foo()
}
```